# Fetching invalid structured attributes with Simple Html DOM

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am trying to fetch an anchor tag, but it's structured poorly.
Something like this:

```
<a  target='_blank' title='Some'href='somelink.html'>Link 1</a>
```

I tried to obtain the valid attributes by using

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $links)
 {
     var_dump($links->attr);
 }
```

And the `var_dump` clearly shows that the `href` attribute is not listed among the other attributes.

How do I find the anchor?

Comment: Take the whole tag text and try to parse it yourself

Comment: @RoyalBg Can you be more specific on it thanks

Comment: well, that's an aweful html code which can justify the use of [`regex`](http://regex101.com/r/lZ2nC1/1) in this case :P

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = "<a  target='_blank' title='Some'href='somelink.html'>Link 1</a>";
//or $html = file_get_contents('example.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

$nodes = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $a->length; $i++) {
    $attr1 = $a->item($i)->getAttribute('target');
    $attr2 = $a->item($i)->getAttribute('title');
    $attr3 = $a->item($i)->getAttribute('href');
    $nodes[] = array('target'=>$attr1, 'title'=>$attr2, 'href'=>$attr3);
}
print_r($nodes);
```